# How to remove spaces in path?

Tags: c#, process, path, whitespace, command-line-arguments

i have to start process which is placed inside Program Files. But the problem is that Process.Start does not taking space in path.

```
Process regeditProcess = Process.Start("regedit.exe", "/s C:\\Program Files\\Test Folder\\sample.reg");
```

Path:

```
C:\\Program Files\\Test Folder\\sample.reg
```

there is a space between Program and Files in 'Program Files'.
Thats my problem. How to avoid space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass command line arguments, containing spaces, in quotes ("), like this:

```
Process regeditProcess = Process.Start("regedit.exe", "/s \"C:\\Program Files\\Test Folder\\sample.reg\"");
```

Answer (score 3):

`Process.Start` is not the problem here, the problem is that regedit.exe doesn't accept spaces in the parameter. Put it into quotes:

```
Process.Start("regedit.exe", "/s \"C:\\Program Files\\Test Folder\\sample.reg\"");
```

also, you should use `%ProgramFiles%` or something equivalent to get the program files folder instead of hardcoding `"C:\\Program Files"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to get Program files

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)
```

Here is more detailed code

```
if(Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
{
Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86)
}
else
{
Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper thing to do would be to quote the path that contains spaces.  So the argument string should be like this:

```
"/s \"C:\\Program Files\\Test Folder\\sample.reg\""
```

Though when working with paths, you generally should always use verbatim literal strings.

```
@"/s ""C:\Program Files\Test Folder\sample.reg"""
```

Otherwise, you could convert the path using 8.3 names.  I don't know of any methods to do this for you in the framework but the rules are simple.  If you have a long name that is longer than 6 characters, you take the first 6 non-space characters and append it with tilde (`~`) followed by a number (usually starting with `1`).  If multiple files have the same 6 characters, the number is incremented in alphabetical order.  So in your case it could be written:

```
@"/s C:\Progra~1\TestFo~1\sample.reg"
```